# Determine allocated 'Handle' types

Tags: c#, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I'm debugging an application I suspect is leaking win32 handles.  Task manager reports the application has some 5000 handles allocated.

Using task manager, I counted the GDI and user objects, and found the number to be 350 and 73.  I verified this count with the "GetGuiResources" function.

Using ProcessExplorer, I took a look at the open handles in the bottom pane.  There are some file handles and DLLs listed, but not nearly 5000.

How can I go about determining the types of those 5000 allocated handles?  Where are they coming from?

Comment: Use a debugger.  Step through the code and look for an increase.  Whatever you stepped over that caused an increase requires a closer look.

Answer (score 4):

Attach WinDbg to the process and type

```
!handle
```

It will print you list of handles and a summary at the end. Example:

```
>!handle
 ... 
Handle c28
  Type          File
Handle c2c
  Type          Section
Handle c30
  Type          File
Handle c34
  Type          Event
Handle c44
  Type          Event
Handle c48
  Type          File
Handle c4c
  Type          Section
Handle c50
  Type          File
636 Handles
Type            Count
None            10
Event           267
Section         126
File            132
Directory       2
Mutant          16
WindowStation   2
Semaphore       3
Key             17
Thread          37
Desktop         1
IoCompletion    3
Timer           3
KeyedEvent      1
TpWorkerFactory 16
```